# What tools does Rust provide to avoid copies when using MPSC channels?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm creating a multithreaded application using `mpsc` to share memory between my threads:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Msg {
    pub content: Vec<i16>,
    /* ... */
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MsgBack {
    pub content: Vec<i16>,
    pub new_content: Vec<i16>,
    /* ... */
}

fn child(rx: mpsc::Receiver<Msg>, tx: mpsc::Sender<MsgBack>) {
    let message = rx.recv().unwrap();
    let new_content = message.content.iter().map(|x| -x).collect();

    tx.send(MsgBack { // The memory is moved/copied
        content: message.content,
        new_content: new_content,
    });
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<Msg>, Receiver<Msg>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_back, rx_back): (Sender<MsgBack>, Receiver<MsgBack>) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        child(rx, tx_back);
    });

    let message = Msg {
        content: (0..100).map(|x| x).collect(), // Dummy initialisation
    };
    println!("{:#?}", message);
    tx.send(message).unwrap(); // The memory is moved/copied

    let answer = rx_back.recv().unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", answer);
}
```

I did some profiling and I saw that sending the data is responsible for 1/3 of the execution time in my real program (which sends more than just a `Vec`).

I want to keep this code structure but avoid moves/copies when sending a message to save a lot of time.

Comment: Consider measuring again with boxed messages (`Box<Msg>`). Unless you're willing to expose a fully reproducible example, we might not be able to be more useful than this.

Comment: @E_net4: I am also wondering if this could be a contention issue, exacerbated by the fact that the lock is held while copying the `Msg`.

Comment: Of course, you profiled the `--release` version, right :) ?

Comment: I'll try using `Box`. Yes I profiled with `--release` and using Valgrind

Comment: Using `Box` did not change anything, it seems weird... I can see that `memcpy` is called a huge amount of time but I don't know where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move of a `Vec` doesn't move its content, but only the 3-word "header". Therefore, unless your `MsgBack` contains *a lot* of other fields or large  fixed-size arrays inline, it should be rather cheap to move.

In general, you can put things in `Box` to allocate them on the heap, so then the `Box<T>` itself is only pointer-sized. "Moving" of the `Box` doesn't move any data, only copies the pointer.

---

If your actual iterators are more complex than your example and don't have useful [`size_hint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint), you may be seeing `memcpy` from `.collect()` reallocating the vector as it grows. You can avoid that by pre-allocating required size:

Instead of:

```
let dst = iterator.collect();
```

use:

```
let mut dst = Vec::with_capacity(required_size);
dst.extend(iterator);
```

Comment: @soocks — you [already stated that using a `Box` did **not** help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365248/what-tools-does-rust-provide-to-avoid-copies-when-using-mpsc-channels#comment85766165_49365248). Would you comment explaining what the actual solution was?